# c++ - 3 bears in a vector of a struct, how can I change this code so the specific bear at the exit is removed?

Tags: c++, vector

```
    void updateGameData(const char g[][SIZEX], vector<Item>& bears, vector<Item>& bombs, Item& detonator, Item& exit, const int key, string& message, int& bearsSaved, bool& bombsActive, int& moves)
{ //move bear in required direction
    bool isArrowKey(const int k);
    void setKeyDirection(int k, int& dx, int& dy, int& moves);
    void gameLost(string& message);
    assert(isArrowKey(key));

    //reset message to blank
    message = "                                         ";      //reset message to blank

    //calculate direction of movement for given key
    int dx(0), dy(0);
    setKeyDirection(key, dx, dy, moves);
    //save number of bears saved ready to output later for the user

    //check new target position in grid and update game data (incl. bear coordinates) if move is possible
    for (unsigned int bearNo = 0; bearNo < bears.size(); ++bearNo)
    {
        switch (g[bears.at(bearNo).y + dy][bears.at(bearNo).x + dx])
        {           //...depending on what's on the target position in grid...
            case TUNNEL:        //can move
            {
                bears.at(bearNo).y += dy;   //go in that Y direction
                bears.at(bearNo).x += dx;   //go in that X direction
            }
                break;
            case WALL:          //hit a wall and stay there
            {
                cout << '\a';   //beep the alarm
                message = "CANNOT GO THERE!";
            }
                break;
            case BOMB:
            {
                bears.at(bearNo).y += dy;   //go in that Y direction
                bears.at(bearNo).x += dx;
                    //sets the bomb to active, how to pass this through to cheat??
                if (bombsActive)
                {
                    cout << "\a";
                    message = "BOOM!";
                    bears.clear();  // Remove all bears from the vector/end the game
                    if (bears.size() == 0)
                        gameLost(message);
                }
            }
                break;
                // The pop_back function only removes the last item in a (non-empty) vector, causing the size of the vector to decrease automatically.  
                // To remove an item knowing its position on the vector the above has been used (bears.begin() + 0 removes the first element)
            case DETONATOR:
            {
                bears.at(bearNo).y += dy;   //go in that Y direction
                bears.at(bearNo).x += dx;   //go in that X direction, means the bear can walk over the detonator and that it reappears afterwards
                cout << "\a";
                message = "BOMBS DISABLED!";
                bombs.clear();
            }
                break;
            case EXIT:
            {
                // Case for the exit symbol on the grid, if a bear walks into it that bear 'escapes' by being removed from the vector, and then the amount of
                // bears saved by the user is increased and incorporated into their high score
                cout << "\a";
                message = "BEAR IS FREE!";
                bears.erase(bears.begin() + ((bears.at(bearNo).y) || (bears.at(bearNo).x))); //I'm assuming it's because of the bears.begin line, but I don't know how to otherwise change it to delete the bear at the y || x coordinate
                bearsSaved++;
            }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The case for exit is where I'm having the issue - as soon as a bear reaches the same coordinate at the exit, any bear in particular seems to disappear and another bear, that may be at the other side of the map, is placed at the side of the exit.

```
bears.erase(bears.begin() + ((bears.at(bearNo).y) || (bears.at(bearNo).x))); 
//I'm assuming it's because of the bears.begin line, but I don't know
//how to otherwise change it to delete the bear at the y || x coordinate
```

For reference I've included some images that better illustrate what I'm talking about. There's other code where the bears are drawn and the grid (the name of my array) are initialised as well, but I don't think they're relevant.

[The before image (the @ symbols are the bears, the X is the exit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZreC.png)

[The after image, the bear near the T has disappeared, instead of the one in the exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HN5P4.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you meant by `bears.begin() + ((bears.at(bearNo).y) || (bears.at(bearNo).x))`, but the result of an `||` expression used as an `int` will always be either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @aschepler I'm trying to remove a bear from a position in the vector; the position (bear being removed) being whichever one managed to walk into the exit. But that makes sense, thanks for clarifying. Any tips on how I can go about doing what I need to.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the delete itself, or with the aftermath of continuing to iterate over a vector you just deleted something from? I'd say if you are going to use an iterator anyway, you might as well use an iterator to iterate.  Just be aware of what happens when you delete (look at the docs on erase, looking for phrases like "invalidates the iterator").  But you can usually get around that by storing the iterator to the object to be deleted in a temporary variable, incrementing the iterator, then calling erase on the temp iterator referring to what you want to delete.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks for the response Kenny, the issue is that I can't delete a particular item from the vector based on a condition. Effectively what I want to try and do is delete the element(bear) that happens to walk into the exit. By my logic and in pseudocode, and with regards to my program I'd expect this to be something along the lines of: `erase(bear).at.thesecoordinates`. Since I can't clear the vector, or otherwise use an iterator (since it may be the second bear, or the third, depending on which reaches the exit first), I'm unsure how to go about removing the specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an iterator type to delete. For proof, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

bears.begin() is an iterator referring to the first bear.

bears.begin() + 1 is an iterator referring to the second bear.

bears.begin() + 2 an iterator referring to is the third ...

Your code is

```
bears.erase(bears.begin() + ((bears.at(bearNo).y) || (bears.at(bearNo).x)));
```

so you are deleting either the first or second bear, depending on the result of this expression (something1 || something2). Logical or can only be true or false, which will then be 0 or 1 when you convert it to an int to increment the iterator returned by bears.begin()

Besides the number being wrong, it doesn't make sense. You want to delete a bear from the vector of bears.  Therefore where the bear is on the game board is completely irrelevant.  If you use x or y, it's probably wrong.

If you want to delete the bear at bearNo, you could use

```
bears.erase( bears.begin() + bearNo )
```

But that will cause the for loop to be wrong. The next bear moves to bearNo, but you never look at it. The easiest fix is to start at the back and iterate forward. That way, when you change the vector, you don't change anything in the part you have not yet evaluated.  (This will change some of the tricks players can exploit if they know which bear is which -- if you want no change to the code you will have to handle incrementing bearNo inside the for loop based on whether or not you deleted a bear.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
struct bear_type { int x, y; };
static const int XSIZE = 10;
static const int YSIZE = 10;

int main(){
    char gameboard[XSIZE][YSIZE];
    memset(gameboard, '\0', sizeof(gameboard));
    gameboard[3][3] = 'D';

    std::vector<bear_type> bears = {{ 5, 7 }, { 3, 3 }, { 0, 0 }};

    for (int bearnum = bears.size()-1; bearnum >= 0; --bearnum){
        const bear_type &bear = bears[bearnum];
        char gamepiece = gameboard[bear.x][bear.y];
        if ('D' == gamepiece){
            bears.erase(bears.begin() + bearnum);
        }
    }
}
```

If you used iterator based iteration, there are some other ways to do it, like std::remove_if, but I didn't want to mess with your code too much.

Comment: thanks for the response again, very much appreciated. The step by step explanation was really useful, and decrementing instead of iterating so we know what's in the vector/array makes a lot more sense to me now as well. I upvoted you too but still not enough rep. Take it easy!